# Is every minor-closed class of graphs that excludes some $S_n$ or $P_n$ of bounded tree-width or clique-width?

Tags: graph-theory

Does every minor-closed class of graphs that excludes some $S_n$ or $P_n$ have (one or more of) bounded tree-width or bounded clique-width?

By $S_n$ I mean a star with $n$ leaves and by $P_n$ I mean a path of length $n$, if that notation isn't standard.

The background is that I'm looking for some characterization of these classes of graphs that makes them "simpler" than other minor-closed graph classes in some way, so if this is untrue then any other similar suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: Do you mean excluded as a minor, topological minor, subgraph, or induced subgraph?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's true that every minor closed class of graphs  has bounded local treewidth  and then omitting path of length n makes things trivial.